# Unity Aiming Line 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanted to create a game where the player should shoot a target. I want to draw a line from the players position to the mouse position and when the player hits space the line disappears and the bullet flies in that direction.

I have this code for showing the bullet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
          Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
      Instantiate(bulletPrefab,firePoint.position,firePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you need to achieve what you want are [Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html), the unity [lineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html#:%7E:text=%20To%20create%20a%20Line%20Renderer:%20%201,other%20display%20settings%20of%20the%20line.%20More) and maybe [Debug.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) to debug your directions in the screen.

For the concrete step of drawing the line you need to set the `Input.mousePosition` to the lineRenderer positions with [SetPositions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html) in an `Update()` so that when you shoot, you can make the line dissapear disabling the line renderer component, or resetting the positions or with other alternative depending on the behaviour you might need.